# TListView doesn't hide selection when using explorer style

Tags: delphi, selection, delphi-xe4, tlistview

In Delphi XE4 if you set HideSelection to true and use an explorer style TListView (when the selection rectangle has a gradient background like Windows Explorer) clicking on another control will not hide the selection rectangle. It will stay there as if nothing has happened - it will not even turn into a gray rectangle like normally when the Listview doesn't have focus.

Is this a Delphi bug or a "feature" of the MS Listview control? Are there any known workarounds or fixes for this? It's really annoying...

Comment: You can set `ListView.Selected := nil;` in the `OnExit` event.

Comment: @LURD you'd want to restore selection in OnEnter

Comment: Un-set hide selection, they at least turn to gray.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes see my answer. I had to make it `AutoFocus` so it would look natural with mouse movements. Without `AutoFocus`, clicking inside an unfocused `ListView` would make the selection awkward.

Comment: @LURD None of these OnEnter/OnExit based workarounds will feel as nice as virtual

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes that is true.

Comment: @LURD But a lot of people resist the virtual paradigm so you are the bookies favourite in my view! ;-)

Comment: @LURD I told you so!  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "feature" is explained by David, and here is a workaround.

By utilizing the `OnExit` event to save the selection and set selection to nil, you would mimic the wanted behavior. When the `ListView` is focused, restore the selection.
To make it react on the mouse, make the `ListView` focused in the `OnMouseEnter` event.

```
Type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...
  private
    FSelected: TListItem;
  ...
  end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (ListView1.SelCount = 0) and Assigned(FSelected) then
    ListView1.Selected := FSelected;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSelected := ListView1.Selected;
  if Assigned(FSelected) then ListView1.Selected := Nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.SetFocus;
end;
```

Having mentioned this solution, why not go for the simple one, set `HideSelection = false`, and the selected item will turn gray when unfocused, just like Sertac mentioned in a comment.

Comment: On some controls it's completely unnecessary to leave a gray rectangle while the control is not active. I think leaving it there would not be a good UI practise, at least it really bothers me...

Answer (score 4):

This is a *feature* of the underlying control. The delphi code does nothing with the property beyond passing on the `LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS` list view style to the underlying control.

Initially I was surprised by your question. I've never seen the behaviour that you describe. Upon closer inspection I realise that is because all my list views are virtual. That is they set `OwnerData` to `True` and supply content in response to `OnData` events. Doing that is the only workaround that I know of.

Comment: I'll try what you write but I don't really fancy switching to virtual because of this. I understand that Delphi doesn't do anything to the listview, but are you sure it's not badly implemented? Maybe there is a flag or certain new "feature" we're unaware of that Delphi doesn't handle... It would be good to compare this with some MS .NET listview control to see how that behaves!

Comment: It's your call with what you do in your code. I always use virtual list views for all the other benefits that they bring. Non-virtual controls are just awful to use, in my view. But what you do in your program is of course up to you. You asked if this was an issue with Delphi, or a feature of the control. And I gave you my answer. If you don't believe me you can check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm not using virtual list views because the listviews in question are really simple, they usually display a few items only - that's why the focus rectangle is more bothering.

Comment: Most of the benefits of virtual apply for list views with any number of items. Performance is only one benefit, and not the most important in my view. The main benefit is that UI and business logic are decoupled well.